Assigning value to interface argument using DoAndReturn
I have the following method:
func (r *RedisClient) GetStruct(ctx context.Context, key Key, value interface{}) (*time.Duration, error) {
// stuff happens here
}

This method has an interface (and corresponding mock):
type Client interface {
    GetStruct(ctx context.Context, key Key, value interface{}) (*time.Duration, error)
}

I'm attempting to test the method using DoAndReturn, only I'm having trouble assigning value to value
I'm doing the following:
s.mockRedisClient.EXPECT().GetStruct(gomock.Any(), cache.BadgesAll, gomock.AssignableToTypeOf(&models.Badge{})).DoAndReturn(func(ctx context.Context, key cache.Key, value any) (*time.Duration, error) {
        value = []*models.Thing{{ID: 1}}
        duration := time.Minute * 1
        return &duration, nil
    })

Only back in the controller I'm testing, value is always nil. Could anyone point out what I'm missing here? Thanks

All function (and method) parameters are local variables to the function. Assigning anything to them will be lost upon return. You have to pass a (non-nil) pointer and modify the pointed value. Or simply return the value and assign at the caller.

Why use DoAndReturn here? If you're not interested in the value of value, just use .Return(&duration, nil). The whole DoAndReturn is pointless in your example. If you do want to check the values of the arguments, you can either use matchers in the EXPECT().Method(<matchers>), or if you absolutely have to go down the DoAndReturn path, but you're not interested in value, just pass in a function with _ any as the last argument

Setting a function parameter to a different value accomplishes nothing, since everything in go is called by value:
 ... func(..., value any) ... {
        value = []*models.Thing{{ID: 1}}
    })

It doesn't change the variable a the calling site and is basically a no op here.
You can only set something if you have a pointer to that variable, and with any (from your Client interface) you'll have to use reflection (Go Playground):
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

func main() {
    i := 0

    doesNothing(i)

    fmt.Println("After doesNothing:", i)

    changesValue(&i)

    fmt.Println("After changesValue:", i)

    // Output:
    // After doesNothing: 0
    // After changesValue: 42
}

func doesNothing(value any) {
    value = 42
}

func changesValue(value any) {
    r := reflect.ValueOf(value)
    if r.Kind() != reflect.Pointer {
        return
    }

    e := r.Elem()
    if !e.CanInt() {
        return
    }

    e.SetInt(42)
}

When you are sure how you would be called, you can also change the signature of your mock return function (in your case to ..., value *models.Badge):
func changesValue(value *int) {
    *value = 42
}

There is also an example “CaptureArguments” showing storing the value in a global variable.

If you look at the matcher for the value argument, you'd see it's expected to be a pointer (or nil), which is of course passed by value, but the value of a memory address can be used to set values that are then useful to the caller (as is done all the time in C). Reflection is anything but the answer here

Right, so there's a couple of things to consider

Only back in the controller I'm testing, value is always nil. Could anyone point out what I'm missing here?

This statement could be read in a couple of ways: either value is always nil, because that's the case in the code you're testing, in which case you're not interested in that argument outside of checking for nil. You can therefore set up your mock (technically a spy) like so:
s.mockRedisClient.EXPECT().GetStruct(gomock.Any(), cache.BadgesAll, nil).Times(1).DoAndReturn(func(_ context.Context, _ Key, _ any) (*time.Duration, error) {
    d := 1 * time.Minute
    return &d, nil
})

I've specified the arguments I expect to be passed to the call as being anything, a particular key, and a nil value. The DoAndReturn callback I'm specifying, going by your code in particular, doesn't use any of the arguments that the tested code is using, so I just ignored all of them (using _). As I mentioned in my comment, though, if this is the case, then DoAndReturn offers no particular benefit over simply specifying the Return values like so:
d := 1 * time.Minute
s.mockRedisClient.EXPECT().GetStruct(gomock.Any(), cache.BadgesAll, nil).Times(1).Return(&d, nil)

If you want to test multiple calls, with different return values based on the keys being used, you can always do something like this:
values := map[cache.Key]time.Duration{
    cache.BadgesAll: 1 *time.Minute,
    cache.FooBar:    123 *time.Second,
}
s.mockRedisClient.EXPECT().GetStruct(gomock.Any(), gomock.Any(), gomock.Any()).Times(len(values)).DoAndReturn(func(_ context.Context, k cache.Key, _ any) (*time.Duration, error) {
    ret, ok := values[k]
    require.True(t, ok) // ensure the key being passed existed in the map
    return &ret, nil
})

Lastly, you can create a gomock.Matcher type, which is a simple interface:
type Matcher interface {
    // Matches returns whether x is a match.
    Matches(x interface{}) bool

    // String describes what the matcher matches.
    String() string
}

like this:
type keyMatcher struct {
    valid map[cache.Key]struct{} // keys you consider valid
}

func (m keyMatcher) Matches(x any) bool {
    v, ok := x.(cache.Key)
    if !ok {
        return false // input not of type cache.Key
    }
    _, ok = m.valid[v]
    return ok // will return false if key wasn't in the valid map
}

func (m keyMatcher) String() string {
    r := "Matches any of the following keys:"
    for k := range m.valid {
        r = fmt.Sprintf("%s %v", r, k)
    }
    return r
}

Create an instance of this matcher type, and set up your mock with it:
km := keyMatcher{
    valid: map[cache.Key]struct{}{
        cache.BagesAll: {},
        cache.FooBar:   {},
    },
}
s.mockRedisClient.EXPECT().GetStruct(gomock.Any(), km, gomock.Any())

and you're off to the races.

So to get to the other interpretation of what you said (value is always nil): if by that you mean that in your DoAndReturn callback, the value of the argument is always nil, but you really don't expect it to be, then clearly, you have a bug in the code you're trying to test. Without your providing that code, it's hard to say what you're missing there. I'd recommend you step through the test as you run it to see what's going on.
You are using the AssignableToTypeOf, which just wraps the reflect.TypeOf type of its argument in a AssignableToTypeOfMatcher argument. In this case, that would mean that the specified calls either match a nil value, or a pointer to a models.Badge. That's all well and good, so nil definitely is valid. I'm not sure what you were expecting value to be, if not nil or a valid pointer. If you didn't expect a nil value, this brings us back to the code you're actually testing either being wrong, or your having an incorrect understanding of what it does.
Rather than using this AssignableTypeOf, what I personally tend to do in my tests is something more along the lines of this:
s.myMock.EXPECT().Something(gomock.Any()).AnyTimes().DoAndReturn(func(arg any) error {
    switch argT := arg.(type) {
    case *some.PtrType:
        require.NotNil(t, argT)
        // other tests, maybe even
        argT.Field = "set to some value"
    case some.OtherType:
        require.Equal(t, argT.Field, "expected value")
    default:
        return fmt.Errorf("unexpected type passed to Something: %T = %#v", argT, arg)
    }
    return nil
})

Now my mock will accept any number of calls to the Something method, and in my DoAndReturn function, I have a type switch, which checks the type of the argument, the values, and I can interact with them in some way that is relevant to my test. If the argument being passed is of an unknown type, however, I have my mock return an error. I could also add a t.Fail() call in the default case, to stop the test because clearly, something unexpected happened.

Lastly, if you were execting/hoping your setting value to mean the caller (the tested code) now has access to whatever you're setting value to in your test, then you're missing the fact that:
value = []*models.Thing{{ID: 1}}

Is basically reassigning a variable, which according to the way in which you've set up your mock is an incompatible type (it's not assignable to a variable of type *model.Bagage). More to the point, even if you were to change that line to:
value = &model.Bagage{ID: 1}

That still wouldn't matter. If the caller passed in a valid pointer, the value of value would just be the address of that object, and you would just assign a different pointer value in your callback. It wouldn't update the object the caller passed in. To actually set values on the object passed in by the caller, you'd have to do something more like:
vt, ok := value.(*model.Bagage) // type assertion from interface{} to pointer to Bagage
// make sure the type assertion worked, and the pointer is not nil
if ok && vt != nil {
    vt.ID = 1
    // or to assign an entire object to the pointer
    // dereference it, and assign the object you want (not a pointer to it, just change the contents of the memory address
    *vt = model.Bagage{
         ID: 123,
     }
}


@eik Cool, but specifying what calls you expect using the arguments as part of the match isn't a change detector test as such. There's plenty of other, valid, use-cases for it: I might want to differentiate between the first and second call made to a dependency, so I can test how errors are handled/wrapped if the first or second call fails

Yes, and I have mentioned the AssignableTo stuff here, and other ways of differentiating between the two calls. I haven't a clue why you're conflating any of that with change-dector tests is my point. I answered a question, based on limited information, detailing what could be going on here. A silly X considered harmful isn't really useful input, especially seeing as I'm answering a question. If you think OP is writing harmful tests, then mention that either in your answer, or in a comment below the question. Honestly, I get the impression you haven't even read half of what I wrote here
